# What emails will be sent when I change email deliverability to all

Tags: email, sandbox

I'm about to change email administration / deliverability / access level in my sandbox from ' System email only ' to ' All Email '.

I'm concerned that unexpected emails will be sent.  How to know what is in the queue and what will be added to the queue?  I don't want to spam a bunch of prospects or send emails that imply commitments.

Answer (score 2):

The email queue doesn't queue blocked messages, so you don't have to worry about any past emails being "released." However, any scheduled jobs, scheduled reports/dashboards, Time Based Workflow Rules, Time Delay Process Builder actions, and so on could be coming up in the future.

Honestly, you should be in the best position to answer this question yourself by referring to your organization's internal documentation of your org. If you don't have any such documentation, or don't trust it, I wouldn't turn on this setting without first deleting every single email address in the database first, and even that could be a daunting task.

It would be entirely impractical to try and research all the possible ways salesforce could have system processes and admin-defined processes that could trigger sending an email. For example, maybe there's a Campaign trigger that will email everyone when a certain field is set. Once you turn that setting on, anything's game.

Comment: one approach would be to mass edit Contact.email and Lead.email to follow the pattern used by SFDC when a new sandbox is created for Users - e.g. `fred.foo=mycompany.com@example.com` - perhaps with a post sandbox apex batch job. Org size an issue here. This isn't a perfect strategy but can mitigate disasters

Comment: @cropredy Except that's not good enough--you can set email alerts on any custom field of the email variety, too. Hence, a scrubbing would have to be thorough and specific to their configuration. I'd probably write a batch class that scans every object except user and then go through every record with a value in any email field. Still not fun.

Comment: right - makes sense;

Answer (score 1):

All Email means all. Workflow emails, Apex emails, Amex error emails, scheduled report emails, big deal alert emails, anything you can think of to send an email.

I would check out the scheduled job queue; Setup -> Monitor -> Jobs -> Scheduled Jobs to see what's scheduled for reports. maybe background jobs if you have stuff that will edit a record and trigger a workflow email.

Could you spam customers if their email is resolvable? Yup, it's not a fun scenario. Can you spam your users if they change their email address? Yup, did that once VP was not impressed. You gotta be super careful or just keep it turned off and only turn it on when you're testing something that needs an alert sent. But even then if you leave it on for too long a scheduled email could go out and then if the email is resolvable they'll get it.

Comment: +1 for `Yup, it's not a fun scenario` - I have been there; especially for sending emails to Contacts/Leads